# Move Angular Material Dropdown menu to the left

Tags: css, angularjs, html, angular-material

I am using Angular Material. I have successfully created a navigation bar and a dropdown menu.

It looks like this:

[image: angular material nav]

I would like to move the `DROPDOWN` to the left-hand side. Now, it appears around the centre.

**HTML code:**

```
<md-toolbar layout="row" class="md-whiteframe-z3" style="padding: 0px;margin:0px;float: left;">
    <h2>Material NavBar</h2>
    <md-menu>
        <md-button md-menu-origin ng-click="$mdOpenMenu()">Dropdown</md-button>
        <md-menu-content width="2">
            <md-menu-item>
                <md-button>Help</md-button>
            </md-menu-item>
            <md-menu-item>
                <md-button>About</md-button>
            </md-menu-item>
        </md-menu-content>
    </md-menu>
    <md-button aria-label="Go Back">
        Go Back
    </md-button>
    <md-button>Item 1</md-button>
    <md-button>Item 2</md-button>
</md-toolbar>
```

How can the code be modified to move `DROPDOWN` to the left just beside the text `Material NavBar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add `<span flex> </span>` in your code.

```
<md-toolbar layout="row" class="md-whiteframe-z3" style="padding: 0px;margin:0px">
<h2>Material NavBar</h2>
<md-menu>
    <md-button md-menu-origin ng-click="$mdOpenMenu()">Dropdown</md-button>
    <md-menu-content width="2">
        <md-menu-item>
            <md-button>Help</md-button>
        </md-menu-item>
        <md-menu-item>
            <md-button>About</md-button>
        </md-menu-item>
    </md-menu-content>
</md-menu>
<span flex></span>
<md-button aria-label="Go Back">
    Go Back
</md-button>
<md-button>Item 1</md-button>
<md-button>Item 2</md-button>
```

Here is a working Example.
http://codepen.io/next1/pen/RaYNxw

Comment: Wrong direction, should be to the **left**... ;) so add that flex after the menu

Comment: My bad. Check again.

Comment: Such a simple solution, yet I got stuck for a considerable time. Genius!

Comment: always use that `span` element for appropriate alignment of elements.

Comment: nextt1, I tried googling to understand more about `<span flex> </span>` but cannot find a good one. Do you mind providing some link with good documentation on `<span flex> </span>`?

Comment: `flex` is the important concept. check out the offical doc https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/children

Comment: Thanks. I thought `flex` was a html/css concept. Didn't realize it was a angular material concept.

Comment: It is derived from `flexbox` concept of css. It makes alignment of elements very simple and accurate.